# Weird javascript embed code from infogram

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am having issues rendering the embed code from INFOGRAM. Their embed code looks as below:

```
!function(e,t,s,i){var n=\"InfogramEmbeds\",o=e.getElementsByTagName(\"script\")[0],d=/^http:/.test(e.location)?\"http:\":\"https:\";if(/^/{2}/.test(i)&&(i=d+i),window[n]&&window[n].initialized)window[n].process&&window[n].process();else if(!e.getElementById(s)){var r=e.createElement(\"script\");r.async=1,r.id=s,r.src=i,o.parentNode.insertBefore(r,o)}}(document,0,\"infogram-async\",\"https://e.infogram.com/js/dist/embed-loader-min.js\");
```

Why would an embed code look like this? Is this a valid javascript? how do I make it work so I can render the infogram graphs.

It looks like I have to use regex for this? Not so sure what can I do so I can render it using react.